# Adjective for an individual that takes intentional steps for a decitful outcome

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english

'Ulterior Motive' comes to mind, but that doesn't describe the individual.

Example:
I was complaining about a specific behavior a co-worker exhibits that makes our peers request to work with me over him. My girlfriend suggested he was intentionally exhibiting the specific behavior with the intent of generating more work for me and less for himself. I told her I didn't think he was 'smart enough' to practice such deceitful forethought.

Whats a good adjective for this type of behavior? I don't think Machiavellian or deceitful is what I am looking for. What do you all think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**deceitful** -- Deceit implies intention to deceive.

> Adjective: **deceitful**  di'seet-ful
>
> 1. Intended to deceive
>
>    "deceitful advertising"; "smooth, shining, and deceitful as thin ice";
>
>    - fallacious, fraudulent
> 2. Marked by deliberate deceptiveness especially by pretending one set of feelings and acting under the influence of another
>
>    "she was a deceitful scheming little thing";
>
>    - ambidextrous, double-dealing, duplicitous, Janus-faced, two-faced, double-faced, double-tongued
>
> See also: dishonest, dishonorable [US], dishonourable [Brit, Cdn]
>
> Encyclopedia: Deceitful

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=deceitful)

Answer (score 0):

How about conniving? "That conniving little jerk; I KNOW he's faking it just to get out of doing any work!"

con·niv·ing adj.
given to or involved in conspiring to do something immoral, illegal, or harmful.
"a heartless and conniving person" -Google Search Dictionary Box

I did not like their use of the word "conspiring" because I thought that it made it sound as if someone else had to be involved. So I went to see some other definitions.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conniving
I did not like it at all, so I just put the link.

"ex·ploit·a·tive ikˈsploidədiv,ekˈsploidədiv/ adjective
making use of a situation or treating others unfairly in order to gain an advantage or benefit"
-Google Search Dictionary Box
This, I feel, is the word that fits best what your co-worker is doing. For some reason, I thought I should try another dictionary, so I tried Merriam-Webster again.

"Definition of exploitative:exploiting or tending to exploit; especially:unfairly or cynically using another person [situation] or group for profit or advantage"

I added the word in brackets, FYI.

Comment: Actually, the answer for deceitful gave me another possibility; I think "scheming" might fit what you mean as well.

Comment: Could you add a dictionary reference please?

Comment: Hi, Ron. You have offered some good suggestions, but you have not linked to from whence you copied your dictionary definitions. While a minor and likely unintentional instance, this is essentially [_plagiarism_](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Can one really plagiarize a dictionary? Mmm, I guess so when I think about it... different dictionaries have different definitions, right? You are right, though- if I do not say where I got the definition from, it is assumed it was my own. Really, I would have left it at the first sentence but I figured people always want a definition as well, so I just google searched it and copied/pasted the definition provided in the little dictionary search box that now pops up when you search a definition. So, how do you cite that? It may or may not be google dictionary. You can see what I went with. :)